# Generating a plaintext SSL certificate for google maps api for use on esp32

Tags: c++, ssl, embedded, esp32, arduino-ide

## Foreword

I don't know that much about https and SSL, so I may use the wrong wordage for certain things but bear with me I've done as much research as I have the energy for

## Goal:

I am trying to use the [geolocate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/overview) feature of the google maps API on my esp32 wroom-1, but this API requires an https connection, I have seen in other online examples using this [wifi library](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFi.h) with this [http library](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/HTTPClient/src/HTTPClient.h) and passing their SSL certificate as a plaintext string as the second parameter to the `http.begin()` function. The example that I seen used a plaintext SSL certificate in this format:

```cpp
const char* root_ca= \
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
"MIICiTCCAg+gAwIBAgIQH0evqmIAcFBUTAGem2OZKjAKBggqhkjOPQQDAzCBhTEL\n" \
"MAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdyZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4GA1UE\n" \
"BxMHU2FsZm9yZDEaMBgGA1UEChMRQ09NT0RPIENBIExpbWl0ZWQxKzApBgNVBAMT\n" \
"IkNPTU9ETyBFQ0MgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlvbiBBdXRob3JpdHkwHhcNMDgwMzA2MDAw\n" \
"MDAwWhcNMzgwMTE4MjM1OTU5WjCBhTELMAkGA1UEBhMCR0IxGzAZBgNVBAgTEkdy\n" \
"ZWF0ZXIgTWFuY2hlc3RlcjEQMA4GA1UEBxMHU2FsZm9yZDEaMBgGA1UEChMRQ09N\n" \
"T0RPIENBIExpbWl0ZWQxKzApBgNVBAMTIkNPTU9ETyBFQ0MgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGlv\n" \
"biBBdXRob3JpdHkwdjAQBgcqhkjOPQIBBgUrgQQAIgNiAAQDR3svdcmCFYX7deSR\n" \
"FtSrYpn1PlILBs5BAH+X4QokPB0BBO490o0JlwzgdeT6+3eKKvUDYEs2ixYjFq0J\n" \
"cfRK9ChQtP6IHG4/bC8vCVlbpVsLM5niwz2J+Wos77LTBumjQjBAMB0GA1UdDgQW\n" \
"BBR1cacZSBm8nZ3qQUfflMRId5nTeTAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwDwYDVR0TAQH/\n" \
"BAUwAwEB/zAKBggqhkjOPQQDAwNoADBlAjEA7wNbeqy3eApyt4jf/7VGFAkK+qDm\n" \
"fQjGGoe9GKhzvSbKYAydzpmfz1wPMOG+FDHqAjAU9JM8SaczepBGR7NjfRObTrdv\n" \
"GDeAU/7dIOA1mjbRxwG55tzd8/8dLDoWV9mSOdY=\n" \
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
```

And then passed it to the constructor as such: `http.begin(url, root_ca);`

## The questions:

1. I cannot find any tutorials on how to export an SSL certificate in this plaintext fashion on windows 10 anywhere online, I have been able to export a certificate that I made on windows into private files but they are not the plaintext as seen in the desired result. Is this easily doable with windows 10? If so are there any tutorials or instructions readily available?
2. Every place where I could create an SSL certificate asked for a domain, I know this is a realm I could research on my own but could someone who knows more about it explain it to me like I'm 5 with my use case? (i.e. I am using an esp32 arduino, the API I want to contact is google maps, so where should the domain be in this case?)

Thanks in advance,
Ozzie

Comment: There is nothing to export as far I can tell, you need to grab the correct CA certificate in whatever format `http.begin()` expects and pass that to the function. You aren't creating any certificates yourself. The correct CA certificate appears a GlobalSign certificate.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk  I have figured out how to do this with domains in chrome, but now I don't know how to get one for google maps, so I guess the question is now: How would I go about getting a CA certificate from google maps that I can use with my arduino?

Comment: Open the URL in your favourite browser, then view the certificate of the page and grab the topmost certificate from the trust chain, export it as a .pem file.

Comment: Ahh you see I think I'm going to have to use the gcloud CLI for this, seems as if googleapis.com isn't reachable through a browser

Comment: Then can use `openssl s_client -connect www.googleapis.com:443 -showcerts`. That will give the intermediate cert, which is ok as ESP32 probably can't follow the trust chain anyway. Use the last returned cert.

Comment: Wow. You're a wizard. Thank you so much. @rustyx solve for solution credit